# Receive message from server netty nio java

Tags: java, web, server, client, netty

I am trying to figure out how can i create a chat using netty nio server and client code found from [here](https://github.com/pacheco/netty-examples). What I want actually is to figure out how exactly can I use the received messages from both client and server. I have found in the server the following code in the server which types a received message:

```
 public class EchoClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

   public String message;
   @Override
   public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("Got reply: " + msg.toString().trim());
      message = msg.toString().trim();
      ctx.disconnect();
    }
    // How to store the message variable and use it from my main function?????
 }
```

This code stands for the echoClient:

```
public class EchoClient {

  public String host;
  public int port;


  public EchoClient(String host, int port) {

     this.host = host;
     this.port = port;
  }

  public void send(String msg) throws InterruptedException {

      EventLoopGroup eventGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

      Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
      bootstrap.group(eventGroup)
            .remoteAddress(host, port)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class) // TCP server socket
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                    socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(
                            // break stream into "lines"
                            new LineBasedFrameDecoder(EchoServerHandler.LINE_MAX, false, true),
                            new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                            new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                            new EchoClientHandler()
                    );
                }
            });

      ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.connect().sync();
      System.out.println("Connected!");
      f.channel().writeAndFlush(msg).sync();
      System.out.print("Sent: " + msg);
      f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
      eventGroup.shutdownGracefully().sync();
      System.out.println("Done.");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

      EchoClientHandler temp = new EchoClientHandler(); //how can i have access to this variable and the returned message?
      String host ="127.0.0.1";
      int port = 8080;
      EchoClient client = new EchoClient(host, port);
      client.send("Hello world!\n");
      temp.message?
  }
}
```

In the code here there is a printing message, however how can the Object msg is connected with the received message? And how can i use it when i want?

**EDIT:** `public String message` in the `channelRead`   has a value however, inside the main is null. How can I pass correctly the value? Guess that the EchoCLientHandler and EchoClient are different threads than my main function in EchoClient. However, is there a way to read from my main function the received message that got from EchoClientHandler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the `StringEncoder` to encode the incoming `ByteBuf` buffer,`StringDecoder` to decode the outgoing message.  You may want to deal with it similar with `bgTaskGroup.submit(new Sleeper(sleepMillis, ctx.channel()));` in `BGTaskServerHandler` handler.

Comment: Sorry i really not follow you. I want to read the message from my main function of the client. After the connection what to print the message from the main and not from channelRead or to parse it in a new variable.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit? Have update the question including the whole code form client.

Comment: `channelRead` and `main` method are in different threads (asynchronous io). You can use an intermediate data type to store and retrieve from `EchoClientHandler` class.

Comment: Oke I got that part that main and channelRead are from different threads, but how can i store the values in an intermediate data type? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Also I want to retrieve the info not from the EchoClientHandler but from my main function.

Comment: you can declare `List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>()` in main method , add `public EchoClientHandler(List<String> messages){this.messages = messages } ` constructor in `EchoClientHandler ` class, then pass messages into the constructor.

Comment: Are you sure that this can work? What is the difference with the variable messages?

Comment: You must check whether the `messages` is empty or not with while condition, you also can use an `blocking queue` to store `msg`. but they are all unnecessary,  `Netty`  recommends io or custom threads pool  to deal with the buffer rather than main thread.